# Setting up Latency Routing in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routes, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I've been digging in the AWS docs for ages and am at my wits end trying to find non AWS official examples.

How do I decide if I should have failover and latency routing or should I have both?  I currently have the site on Elastic beanstalk with both a dev and production version, but I get a 500 or 502 errors at least a couple times a month where if you refresh the page, it eventually loads but then the CSS is missing or the page doesn’t load and sometimes the page is just slow to load even with caching.  How am I supposed to know if it’s a need for failover or latency routing, or should I have both?  The AWS notifications only say “Environment health has transitioned from Degraded to Severe”.  How do I log where/which AWS server Route 53 had serve the page?

Are you supposed to have multiple EC2 instances for latency based routing?  I’m confused why the docs say to create a latency record for each of my EC2 instances.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/TutorialTransitionToLBR.html

I currently have Codepipeline connected to my Github, so that changes are automatically deployed to the dev site, and then I manually approve changes to production.  If I have multiple EC2 instances, do I need to set up the code pipeline for each EC2 instance such that it’s connected to my Github and then manually approve changes for all instances—ie would I just have multiple copies of the site hosted in diff regions in this situation?  How do people manage this?  I’m assuming there’s some way to approve production launch for all at once if this is what is done but I don't know what to google

Comment: I would assume that the errors are caused by the instance being busy. You could probably avoid that by increasing the size of the Amazon EC2 instance so that it is 'less busy'. Yes, this would incur extra cost, but so would routing to alternative EC2 instances (since you'd need to run those alternate instances). Or, run multiple EC2 instances behind a load balancer so that all instances are always serving demand rather than having some of them only serve traffic in response to temporary failures.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the EC2 instance is a t2 micro, but it's an internal analytics site, so there's probably 30-40 max users, and they're almost never at the same time or does it not make a difference?  I don't understand what the sizing of a EC2 instance does for a site--the memory for a micro is 1 Gb and I don't think it's ever pulling anything close to that much data for a page load?

Comment: A T2 instance is [burstable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html), meaning that it can occasionally burst to higher CPU, but if this is sustained for a long period then the CPU is forcibly limited. This makes it ideal for use-cases where there are occasional bursts of high usage, as long as there are long periods of less usage. You should look at the CloudWatch Metrics for that EC2 instance to see whether there was a high CPU load and a low CPU Credit balance at the times when it generates errors.